# how to use ng-grid to update cells with $http?

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angular and am trying to make a CRUD app with the ng-grid plugin.  I found an example from the web that gets me the info I need, but not a good explanation on how to update the info using a REST route.  Here is the code:
    var cellEditableTemplate = "";

```
// Configure ng-grid
$scope.gridOptions = {
    data: 'myData',
    enableCellEdit: true,
    multiSelect: false,
    columnDefs: [
        { field: 'Id', displayName: 'Id' },
        { field: 'Name', displayName: 'Name', enableCellEdit: true, editableCellTemplate: cellEditableTemplate },
        { field: 'Description', displayName: 'Description', enableCellEdit: true, editableCellTemplate: cellEditableTemplate }
    ]
};


// Update Entity on the server side
$scope.updateEntity = function (column, row) {
    console.log(row.entity);
    console.log(column.field);
    // code for saving data to the server...
    // row.entity.$update() ... <- the simple case
}
```

How do I use the following from the example to update my model?

```
row.entity.$update()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inject `$http` into your controller.

Then in your `$scope.updateEntity`:

```
$scope.updateEntity = function() {
   $http.get('getDataFromServerUrl').success(function(data) {
         //update data
         $scope.gridOptions.data = data;
        }).error(function(err) {
           console.log('Error getting data', err);
        });
 }
```

and then your data will be updated, as `$http` activate the $digest cycle.